# Appending data to all Socket.io client-side emits

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm working on a couple sites that share some Socket.io initialization code. Also shared is a global var. If this var has a value I need to send it over in all socket emits.

I have not been able to figure out a good way to append this variable to all outgoing emits. I was hoping that Socket.io would have a method that is called whenever an emit is fired (just before sending the data), allowing you to add to the data as needed. But, if it exists, I could not find it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but you could save the existing, and write your own `emit` function that does what you want, and then calls the original `emit`.